# FsUnit - The value or constructor 'should' is not defined

Tags: unit-testing, f#, fsunit

OK so I'm looking at FsUnit to develop tests for some F# code, and I'm having a look at the example BowlingGame.fsx on [GitHub](https://github.com/fsharp/FsUnit/tree/master/Examples/NUnit).

To take the first test:

```
[<Test>] 
let ``with simple scores should get the expected score.`` () =
scoreBowls [1;2;3] |> should equal 6
```

I get a red squiggly under should with the compiler error:

```
The value or constructor 'should' is not defined
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Full source code added below.

```
module Calculations.UnitTests

open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

let (|EndOfGame|IncompleteStrike|Strike|Normal|Other|) (l, frame) =
    match l with
    | _ when frame = 11            -> EndOfGame(0)
    | [10;s]                       -> IncompleteStrike(10+s+s)
    | 10::s::n::tail               -> Strike(10+s+n, s::n::tail)
    |  f::s::n::tail when f+s = 10 -> Normal(f+s+n,  n::tail)
    |  f::s::n::tail               -> Normal(f+s,    n::tail)
    | ls                           -> Other(List.fold (+) 0 ls)

let scoreBowls bowls =
    let rec scoreBowls' frame l current_score =
        let nextframe = scoreBowls' (frame+1)
        match (l, frame) with
        | EndOfGame(score)        -> current_score + score
        | IncompleteStrike(score) -> current_score + score
        | Strike(score, l)        -> nextframe l (current_score + score)
        | Normal(score, l)        -> nextframe l (current_score + score)
        | Other(score)            -> current_score + score
    scoreBowls' 1 bowls 0

[<Test>] 
let ``with simple scores should get the expected score.`` () =
    scoreBowls [1;2;3] |> should equal 6

[<Test>]
let ``with a spare should get the expected score (spare).`` () =
    scoreBowls [2;8;1] |> should equal 12

[<Test>]
let ``with a strike should get the expected score (strike).`` () =
    scoreBowls [10;1;2] |> should equal 16

[<Test>]
let ``that is perfect should get a score of 300.``() =
    scoreBowls [for i in 1..18 -> 10] |> should equal 300

[<Test>]
let ``with spares in the last frame should get the expected score (spare in last frame).`` () =
    scoreBowls ([for i in 1..18 -> 0] @ [2;8;1]) |> should equal 11

[<Test>]
let ``with a strike in the last frame should get the expected score (strike in last frame).`` () =
    scoreBowls ([for i in 1..18 -> 0] @ [10;10;1]) |> should equal 21

[<Test>] 
let ``with double strikes should add the score of the first strike to the score of the second.``     () =
    scoreBowls [10;10;1] |> should equal 33

[<Test>]
let ``that looks like an average bowler's game should get the expected score (example game).`` () =
    scoreBowls [1;4;4;5;6;4;5;5;10;0;1;7;3;6;4;10;2;8;6] |> should equal 133
```

Comment: I can't repro this with VS2013 RTM.

Comment: @ildjarn source code added

Comment: @Nick I am not reproducing with VS2013 Express for Desktop and FsUnit from NuGet.  It shows as FsUnit.NUnit 1.3.0.1 in project references.  NUnit is at 2.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referencing a wrong version of FsUnit, incompatible with the Framework you selected? Delete the reference to FsUnit and add it again using NuGet.